MongoDb schema validation error when schema specified ['string'] as bson type of attribute
I have a peice of python code which is using the PyMongo library to insert into my mongodb Collection hosted on MongoDB Atlas.
Im trying to insert the following doc into a collection called Customer deployed on Atlas using an insert_many() call.
{'Source': ['LoanDelivery_2022-03-31'], 'CustID': 1, 'CustName': 'Seexxx', 'CustPhone': '940xxxxx', '_id': ObjectId('66ca8d5873a3fdxxxx')}
The schema for the collection is as follows.
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    title: 'Customers_Schema',
    properties: {
      CustID: {
        bsonType: 'int'
      },
      CustName: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      CustPhone: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      CustAddress: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      Source: {
        bsonType: [
          'string'
        ],
        description: 'Sources of the record'
      }
    },
    required: [
      'CustID',
      'CustName',
      'Source'
    ]
  }
}

I get an error saying considered type of Source is an array while expected type is ['string']. Aren't these two types equivalent, and Pymongo should be able to handle the binary conversion for me automatically? Is there any type conversion i need to handle within my python code before I write to MongoDB?
Heres a snippet of the BulkWriteError object thrown by the write operation
{'operatorName': 'bsonType', 'specifiedAs': {'bsonType': [...]}, 'reason': 'type did not match', 'consideredValue': ['LoanDelivery_2022-03-31'], 'consideredType': 'array'}
special variables
function variables
'operatorName' =
'bsonType'
'specifiedAs' =
{'bsonType': ['string']}
'reason' =
'type did not match'
'consideredValue' =
['LoanDelivery_2022-03-31']
'consideredType' =
'array'


array should be specified differently, see example in this link https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/json-schema-validation--checking-your-arrays

thanks this is helpful..additionally i was also getting a type mismatch error when on my CustID field because the schema was initially defined with a long type in the validation schema on Mongo DB for this collection.  This is depite explicitly casting to python int type before writing to Mongo DB. I have now reverted that to int in the schema, but would be great if you have some pointers on how to work with long type ((int64)) bson attributes in the schema

see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#omissions, long is supported

The problem is that in the scheme description, the type can be specified as an array. i.e. bsonType: 'string' and bsonType: ['string'] are the same.
The corrected schema is following:
   {
    $jsonSchema: {
    title: 'Customers_Schema',
    properties: {
      CustID: {
        bsonType: 'int'
      },
      CustName: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      CustPhone: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      CustAddress: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      Source: {
        bsonType: [
          'array'
        ],
        description: 'Sources of the record',
        minItems: 1,
        items: {
           bsonType: ['string']
        }
      }
    },
    required: [
      'CustID',
      'CustName',
      'Source'
    ]
  }
}


Repeating the comment above in case you can help. Thanks this is helpful..additionally i was also getting a type mismatch error when on my CustID field because the schema was initially defined with a long type in the validation schema on Mongo DB for this collection. This is despite explicitly casting to python int type before writing to Mongo DB. I have now reverted that attribute to int in the schema, but would be great if you have some pointers on how to work with long type ((int64)) bson attributes in the schema without getting an int vs long type mismatch
